# Why was the name "Hibernate" chosen for Java's Hibernate library?

Tags: java, hibernate

Does the term "hibernate" mean something specific with regard to ORM libraries? Is there a story behind it?

Comment: Laptop hibernate, or Java hibernate?

Comment: I have edited the content to java 'Hibernate'

Comment: I can see people are rating in -ve. Don't know the reason.

Comment: -ve? I down-voted 'cause you forgot to specify sufficient context in your initial question. Removed now that you've updated.

Comment: Why is Java called Java?  It's not a kind of coffee, it's a programming language.

Comment: I guess the question was more about why Hibernate for Java but NHibernate for C#? Why wasn't C#'s called the original Hibernate?

Comment: I believe the "n" part of the naming construct is to denote that it is to be used under the .(n)et environment.  same as nUnit, and nMock... Although for Quartz, it's Quartz.NET... but that's my $0.02 on the subject.

Comment: How is this not programming related and not a wiki at the same time ? Should be closed or wiki.

Answer (score 27):

It's pretty clear to me.

An object is sent to hibernation to a RDBMS, when it comes back ( if it does ) it wakes up from his hibernation.

Sleep as "Cinder6" says , is a short term "wait"; much more like the serialization process, your object gets to sleep and wakes up in another node ( or VM )

If an object is sent to a DB it may wait for a week, a month, a year, before it gets fetched again hence it was sent to hibernation.

Answer (score 4):

My WAG: your entities "hibernate" in the database when they're not in use.

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate is about "replacing direct persistence-related database accesses with high-level object handling functions". So it's about data that is sleeping in a database.

Answer (score 4):

Persistence is where data outlives the process that created it. Which in more basic terms means storing the data in non-volatile memory (doesn't get lost when the power's switched off) Nowadays, this usually takes the form of storage within a database.

A problem occurs however because programming languages (such as Java) store data and utilise it in a completely different form to that of a database. So there is a need for a conversion process (objects to db records) and then upon retrieval the opposite (db records to objects). Hibernate is a library that automates this whole process and avoids the potential pitfalls that can occur when converting (known as object relational impedance mismatch)

Therefore Hibernate helps abstract away the whole database element, it's almost as if the objects are being put in storage and then retrieved when needed - or being put 'to sleep' and called again when needed.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you'll find anything authoritative on the matter, but I would say it's a logical choice.  When you sleep, you can wake up pretty easily, and will do so within a shorter amount of time than if you were to hibernate (I'm pretending you are a bear right now).  Since sleep and hibernate are similar, manufacturers probably wanted to extend the metaphor.

**EDIT:**  Well shoot, now it's about a Java library.  So much for my bear theories.

Comment: Also, you must feed your machine several times its size in weight before it goes into hibernation.